# Problem installng Ubuntu along Windows 7

Tags: 11.10, installation, grub2

I am having troubles installing ubuntu 11.10 on my 80gb drive.  Everytime I try it always fails to install the grub boot loader.  I followed the instructions on [on this page](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/10/27/dual-boot-ubuntu-11-10-windows-7-on-a-pc-with-2-hard-drives)

Any help from anyone?

Comment: Please edit your posting and add concrete error messages!If there are no error messages, pls describe the behaviour of the system!

Comment: Also... what did you install first, Ubuntu or Windows? Sometimes that matters because Windows overrides GRUB.

Comment: it said said that it could not install the grub boot loader in the partition i told it to that was mentioned in the instructions i linked to and I told it to try again.  After I told it to try again it seemed to move very fast like something was wrong.

Comment: windows was pre existing and it should not have over ridden anyways because i told it to install the boot manager on the ubuntu drive.

Answer (score 1):

Install the GRUB bootloader to your MBR, **not** to a partition. [i.e. to /dev/**sda** instead of /dev/**sda3**]

You can still boot windows from Grub, and you can always even reinstall the Windows bootloader to the MBR by inserting the Windows 7 disk, select repair, and it will automatically detect the bootloader missing and install it.

Edit: I looked at your comments, do you have a separate *physical* drive for Ubuntu or just a partition?  If you have a separate physical hard disk, you need to either install it to your windows hard drive, or change the boot order of the hard drives in your BIOS so that the Ubuntu disk comes **first**.

Edit 2:  I did not say this, but I also implied you must also install GRUB to the MBR of your Ubuntu drive, in addition to setting it to boot from that first.

Comment: no there are indeed 2 hard drives the ubuntu one is 80gig and the windows one is 300gig.  also i try to change the bios order and yet it still opens windows first

Comment: is there any way i can have it so grub does not install and i just use the windows boot manager instead to launch ubuntu

Comment: No, because the Windows bootloader cannot boot Ubuntu.  It's like trying to boot mac or another random OS with windows' bootloader.  GRUB however supports windows, linux, and unix, bsd, etc.   Now, if you changed the order in BIOS to the 80GB hdd **first** and the 300GB hdd **second,** and it still boots right into windows, your problem is likely there is no GRUB installed to the MBR of the 80GB drive.  You **need** to install GRUB to the MBR, **not** the partition.  As far as I know, partition bootloaders are only useful for chainloading. And you can't chainload b4 you boot from MBR.